# How .NET Parallel.Foreach construct with IO intensive operations

Tags: .net, multithreading, task-parallel-library, parallel.foreach

Say, I write a program which is supposed to read all text files in a given and produce a list of objects of out of it.

So steps are

1. Read File content From Disk for all files in the given folder.
2. Create unique object per file content.

I'm questioning if Parallel.ForEach in .NET (or any other parallelism construct) will improve performance of step 1 and how.  Aren't disk's IO are synchronous in nature i.e. The head of a disk can not be in 5 places at the same time.  As a matter of fact it may make things slower?

What are your thoughts on this?

Comment: SSDs are ubiquitous nowadays and are not affected anywhere near as much by random reads. Also a RAID drive (or a SAN) can do big parallel operations. But if you are fundamentally IO-bound waiting on the disk (not doing a lot of processing) then no it does not make sense to go parallel. If your code is heavy on the CPU, that's when you use parallelism, eg (de)compression, encryption / decryption

Comment: @Charlieface your comment would make a decent answer.

Comment: *DON'T* use `Parallel.ForEach` with IO. That's it. `Parallel.For/ForEach` are meant for data parallelism - processing a *lot* of in-memory data, by partitioning the data and using every available core to process the partitions. IO on the other hand, doesn't use the CPU. Using `Parallel.ForEach` would just block all cores doing very little.

Comment: `Aren't disk's IO are synchronous in nature` on the contrary, IO is always asynchronous in Windows. Blocking is *emulated* at the OS level to make programming easier. As for increasing performance, async/concurrent operations can increase performance up to a point. Disk IO is cached a LOT - on the disk itself, on the disk controller, the OS itself. This means that concurrent operations may not even hit the disk, reading the file from some cache. Opening/closing files has CPU-based overhead too, due to file management operations

Answer (score 3):

Let's distinguish two different concepts:

- **Concurrency**: Doing more than one thing at a time.
- **Parallelism**: Doing lots of work by dividing it up among multiple threads that run concurrently.

*(These definitions are from [Stephen Cleary's Concurrency in C# Cookbook](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/149205450X).)*

Concurrency does not require multiple executors. It could work with a single one and it can use **context switching** to make progress on each task. (At a given point in a time it suspends the execution of a given task and it switches to another job.)

On the other hand when we talk about parallel processing then we can assume that there are multiple available executors and that's why multiple jobs can make progress at the same time.

[image: Concurrent vs Parallel]
[Source](https://www.raywenderlich.com/5370-grand-central-dispatch-tutorial-for-swift-4-part-1-2)

---

In case .NET when we talk about Parallel Programming most of the time we refer to [CPU bound operations](http://www.albahari.com/threading/part5.aspx). That's why `Parallel.Foreach`, `Parallel.For` and `Parallel.Invoke` are designed for multi-threading.

If you visit the [related MSDN article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/how-to-write-a-simple-parallel-foreach-loop) then it would be misleading at the first sight. It uses an example which reads files from a given folder. But please pay attention to this comment:

```cs
Parallel.ForEach(files, (currentFile) =>
{
    // The more computational work you do here, the greater the speedup compared to a sequential foreach loop.
```

So, depending on the work what you want to do, `Parallel.XYZ` or PLinq may not be the best choice. If you want to execute multiple async I/O operations concurrently then `Task.WhenAll` is your best friend.

---

If you want to better understand parallel programming then I would suggest to read Stephen Toub's excellent whitepaper: [Patterns of Parallel Programming C#](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=19222)

I would also encourage you watch Jeffry Richter's presentations about [async I/O](https://channel9.msdn.com/Series/Microsoft-SWIT-2014/swit5) and [scalable applications](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xGSabgBo-S8).

Answer (score 3):

Firstly, SSDs are ubiquitous nowadays and are not affected anywhere near as much by random reads as were the old HDDs. A RAID setup (or a SAN) can also do big parallel operations.

But **if you are fundamentally IO-bound** i.e. you are waiting on the disk and not doing a lot of processing, then **no, it does not make sense to go parallel**. All that will happen is you will have more waiting threads, and as you say, also more random reads and less sequential.

It may make sense to have one thread just do I/O and another couple to do processing, this way the I/O queue depth remains deep because new requests are constantly coming through.

---

If your code is heavy on the **CPU** and is **not** limited as much by I/O, that is when you use full parallelism. For example de/compression, encryption and decryption.

Comment: For CPU bound code, Parallelism will only help if you are on multi core/multi processor system correct.  For "HDD being Synchronous", what I meant to say that jobs (read/write) will be queued up for the "Storage Device Driver" queue and it will pick and process them one at a time.

Comment: Parallelism is always advised only up to the number of processor threads, so that's the same thing as single-threaded on a single-thread processor (who has one nowadays?), yes the queue will be deep but it will still have to do a lot of random seeks