# Parallel.ForEach use case

Tags: c#, multithreading, performance, parallel.foreach

I am wondering if I should be using `Parallel.ForEach()` for my case. For a bit of context: I am developing a small music player using the NAudio library. I want to use `Parallel.ForEach()` in a factory method to quickly access .mp3 files and create `TrackModel` objects to represent them (about 400). The code looks like this:

```
public static List<TrackModel> CreateTracks(string[] files)
{
    // Guard Clause
    if (files == null || files.Length == 0) throw new ArgumentException();

    var output = new List<TrackModel>();

    TrackModel track;

    Parallel.ForEach(files, file =>
    {
        using (MusicPlayer musicPlayer = new MusicPlayer(file, 0f))
        {
             track = new TrackModel()
             {
                 FilePath = file,
                 Title = File.Create(file).Tag.Title,
                 Artist = File.Create(file).Tag.FirstPerformer,
                 TrackLength = musicPlayer.GetLengthInSeconds(),
             };
         }

         lock (output)
         {
             output.Add(track);
         }
   });

   return output;
}
```

Note: I use `lock` to prevent multiple Threads from adding elements to the list at the same time.

My question is the following: Should I be using `Parallel.ForEach()` in this situation or am I better off writing a normal foreach loop? Is this the right approach to achieve better performance and should I be using multithreading in combination with file access in the first place?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66146811/how-net-parallel-foreach-construct-with-io-intensive-operations I'd suspect there's not much improvement if any, reading tags are really light on CPU

Comment: Parallelism would make sense here, if you can make use of async file IO. Although I wouldn't use `Parallel.ForEach` for that. Also, you seem to call `File.Create` twice?

Comment: @marsze Thank you so much for the observation! I have been doing it wrong all along by calling `File.Create` multiple times. I also realized that `Taglib.File` inherits from `IDisposable`, meaning I can add it to the `using`.  Great suggestion!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're better off avoiding both a `foreach` and `Parallel.ForEach`. In this case `AsParallel()` is your friend.

Try this:

```
public static List<TrackModel> CreateTracks(string[] files)
{
    if (files == null || files.Length == 0) throw new ArgumentException();

    return
        files
            .AsParallel()
            .AsOrdered()
            .WithDegreeOfParallelism(2)
            .Select(file =>
            {
                using (MusicPlayer musicPlayer = new MusicPlayer(file, 0f))
                {
                    return new TrackModel()
                    {
                        FilePath = file,
                        Title = File.Create(file).Tag.Title,
                        Artist = File.Create(file).Tag.FirstPerformer,
                        TrackLength = musicPlayer.GetLengthInSeconds(),
                    };
                }
            })
            .ToList();
}
```

This handles all the parallel logic and the locking behind the scenes for you.

Comment: I would add `.AsOrdered()` after the `.AsParallel()`, the get the `TrackModel`s in the original order of the `files`. I would also add `.WithDegreeOfParallelism(2)`, because I consider highly unlikely for a parallelization level more than 2 to be beneficial, when we are talking about reading and writing from the file-system. Unless the hardware is not a HDD or a SSD, but some exotic storage device from the future. 

Answer (score 0):

Combining the suggestion from comments and answers and adapting them to my code I was able to solve my issue with the following code:

```
public List<TrackModel> CreateTracks(string[] files) 
{
    var output = files
                     .AsParallel()
                     .Select(file =>
                     {
                         using MusicPlayer musicPlayer = new MusicPlayer(file, 0f);
                         using File musicFile = File.Create(file);

                         return new TrackModel()
                         {
                             FilePath = file,
                             Title = musicFile.Tag.Title,
                             Artist = musicFile.Tag.FirstPerformer,
                             Length = musicPlayer.GetLengthInSeconds(),
                         };
                     })
                     .ToList();
    return output;

}
```

Using `AsParallel()` helped significantly decrease the loading time which is what I was looking for. I will mark [Enigmativity](https://stackoverflow.com/users/259769/enigmativity)'s answer as correct because of the clever idea. Initially, it threw a weird `AggregateException`, but I was able to solve it by saving the output in a variable and then returning it.

Credit to [marsze](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2060966/marsze) as well, whose suggestion helped me fix a memory leak in the application and shave off 16MB of memory (!).

Comment: Whatever was the reason for the `AggregateException`, it's unlikely that the `output` variable solved the problem. It might be an intermittent error that you'll observe again in the future. Tip: the `AggregateException` has an [`InnerExceptions`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.aggregateexception.innerexceptions) property, where the real exceptions are stored.